# Function to count how many times a keyboard macro is invoked?

Tags: keyboard-macros

I am quite bad at counting and remember how many times I have invoked a special command, so I wonder is there any way to count and show in the minibuffer how many time a keyboard macro was invoked? Say that I want to use the macro to navigate the buffer in a specific way, and increment a counter as I move.

Comment: To understand why you need a macro for that, is the application something that is different each time and you need to record a macro for that? Or would it be fine to instead write a little elisp function with a `message` from at the end?

Comment: Hi, a function that increments a counter and saves the state of the counter each time a specific macro is invoked and of course message me about how many times it was invoked would suffice, elisp is not my strong side however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Initialize some counter variable, say `counter`, to 0. `(setq counter 0)`
2. Define the macro
3. Give the macro a name, say "some-macro" by `C-x C-k n` (`kmacro-name-last-macro`)
4. `M-x insert-kbd-macro`. This will dump the macro out as Lisp code.
5. Add `(setq counter (1+ counter))` to the Lisp code as follows:

   `(fset 'some-macro
     (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") 
     (setq counter (1+ counter)) (kmacro-exec-ring-item ...... arg)))`
6. Evaluate the s-exp.
7. Execute your macro by `M-x some-macro`. If you find this cumbersome,
   just define another keyboard to do this...
8. To check how many times you've replayed the macro, just evaluate the variable `counter`.

Comment: Thank you, I wrote: (fset 'test
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p")
     (setq counter( + 1 counter)) (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([return 32 49 50 51] 0 "%d")) arg)
     (print counter))) Seems to be working and output the number of invocations in the minibuffer!